How to synchronize data from SAP to an external database?
Our goal: Synchronize a delta of SAP tables to an external SQL Server database without complex ABAP reports. We are using an SAP ECC 6.0 EHP8 system.
In our current landscape, we are running RFC-function modules, which are called by an external program to synchronize daily data from SAP to a SQL Server database. Since this landscape keeps growing and growing, I need to find a more professional way to solve this task.
We are synchronizing SAP standard tables and custom tables.
How is this task solved properly? Is there a way to log every transaction on a table and synchronize the changed data periodically?
Currently, we are looking for a way to activate a trigger on the SAP database, but I am not sure if this is a good way to solve this problem.

One of the easiest patterns is destination system sends timestamp of last sync. Source system queries data that changed after timestamp and returns it. Destination system should have a scheduled job.

You can also check CDHDR and CDPOS tables at least for changed datas in  standard processes.

Sorry, that my question wasnt as clear as I thought.
We are running a sap system ECC 6.0 EHP8. The destination is a MS SQL DB. And there is a middleware created on our own. (.net C#)
The answer of Eray was already checked and isn't solving completly.
The answer of Zero isnt doable because we dont have the needed information at every table in sap ( if i am correct )

We are currently trying to implement this :
link

@NIRR What's your ECC database? There is no such thing as 'SAP ECC-to-MS SQL replication' because SAP runs on multiple databases. If it's MS SQL Server, version 2008+, you can configure DB replication as the latter supports delta replication. If DB vendors are different, then most viable solution will be triggers+ABAP reports, depending on the scope of replicated tables.
